# PouchDB slow on insert when I have 4k+ items in DB

Tags: angular, ionic2, pouchdb

I have an app that based on ionic2 and uses PouchDB for saving and sync data.

In the case when I have 4k+ items in DB, sometimes new post cat take 20+ seconds.

The issue reproduces only on iOS devices but works perfectly in Chrome on the laptop.

`Platform: iOS
Ionic: 2
PouchDB: 6.1.1
Adapter: websql`

What part can I check for improving performance?

Comment: This might help https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4632

Comment: Not helped that conversation

Comment: Provided more debug information https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6675